# Can I share a question with someone else on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, sharing

Often I bump into an interesting question on Stack Overflow and would like to link it to my friend but I'm at work so I'm not logged into any outer social network.

Can I somehow share a link to some other account on Stack Exchange?

I thought since you can already "Continue a discussion with someone in chat" after you both leave too many comments, you could send someone a link the same way. I just don't see how to trigger this chat.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have more than social media to share a post. You can copy the link (click on *share* under the post and copy the URL) and send it through your email account, by smoke signals, etc.

SE only facilitates sending through Google+, Facebook and Twitter, so if you want to share it otherwise, you have to do this your own.

Comment: I thought since you can already "Continue a discussion with someone in chat" after you both leave too many comments, you could send someone a link the same way. I just don't see how to trigger this chat

Comment: It is done automatically. And chatting isn't really 'sharing', it is for discussion things related to a post.

Comment: @ditoslav well if you have more than 100 reputation and the other user has more than 20, you can start a chat room with that user. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244337/tutorial-on-starting-stack-exchange-chat/244347#244347), under "Inviting a user to chat".